# Adding elements to an immutable list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, insertion-order

In Scala the way you add elements to an immutable list as follows:

```
    val l = 1 :: 2 :: Nil
    l: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

What this means is you first create a Nil (Empty) List, and to that you add 2 and then 1. i.e. These operations are right-associated. So, effectively, it can be re-written in a clearer way, like so:

```
    val l = (1 :: (2 :: Nil))
    l: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

The question is, if List is supposed to preserve the order of insertion, and if 2 is added first to an empty list and then 1 is added, then why is the answer not `l: List[Int] = List(2, 1)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because elements are prepended: first `2` then `1`.

From definition of cons method:

```
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
    new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

here you can see that each time new instance of case class `scala.collection.immutable.::` is created:

```
case class ::[B](val head: B, var tail: List[B]) extends List[B]
```

you just use your new element as a `head` for new list and your whole previous list as its `tail`.

Also prepend operation for immutable `List` takes constant time O(1), append is linear O(n) (from Scala [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)).

Comment: Correct. But I think the key point is, to get the correct order we need to do list.reverse ... right?

Comment: `::` is prepend operation. If you want your list to change the order, then Yes,  `list.reverse` is the best solution.

Comment: This is correct of course, but "prepend" is just a label. We could swap the names of `prepend` and  `append`, `head` and `last`, etc. and we'd still have a conceptually consistent model for what the list does, and then printing the list as `List(2, 1)` would make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention. Lists are basically stacks. It's most efficient to access or modify the most-recently added items. You could just as well consider the head of the list to be the final item ordinally, in which case, your suggested notation would be appropriate.

I would speculate that the reason for the convention is that we don't typically put much care into how a list was constructed, but we do often want to consider the first item accessed to be the initial item in the ordering, and so the notation reflects that.